# How to refresh a table in template of Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am currently obtaining an object from my views and displaying it in the template in form of a table. Currently I am struck at the part that we need to refresh the table/div, without refreshing the page.

In my views.py

```
def foo(request):
  testruns......
  render_to_response('pages/bar.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My bar.html (template)

```
<div id = "roman">
    {% for trun in testruns %}

        <tr>
            <td>{{ trun.testprofile }}</td>
            <td>{{ trun.time }}</td>
            <td>{{ trun.testresult }}</td>
            <td>{{ trun.state }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

There are two approaches which are supposed to work:

- Using [dajaxice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759210/refreshing-table-with-dajaxice-in-django)
- Using [Jquery]

  ```
     $.ajax({

     url: '{% url myview %}',
            success: function(data) {
            $('#the-div-that-should-be-refreshed').html(data);
            }
     });
  ```

I would like to know which approach is more suitable to my case. Using Approach 2, would the table auto refresh, and how do we set the time to refresh ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use knockoutJS http://knockoutjs.com/ instead of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both acceptable but disadvantages of the second approach(pulling table from django as html ):

1. Carried data over network is much bigger
2. If u use something javascript based components in your table (maybe
   dojo based buttons etc.) they may cause some problems. I had a
   smilar issue in dojo and i found the solution  in make dojo reparse
   the applied html. But life could not be easy everytime so first
   approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only place where you need an auto-refresh, your approach 2 should work along with setting a timer to do the auto-refresh. You can use the `setInterval` function for the purpose:

```
// Refresh the Table every 5 seconds
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({    
       url: '{% url myview %}',
          success: function(data) {
          $('#the-div-that-should-be-refreshed').html(data);
          }
    });
}, 5000)
```

But if you are planning on developing a responsive webpage, where the whole UI needs to be kept updated, then I would suggest to use a full fledged framework like [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)