# Updating data tables in Django from JSON

Tags: jquery, python, json, django, heroku

I'm pretty new to web development, and I'm trying to implement a webpage in Django that displays a dynamic data table. I would like the data table to display all objects in the database, and when a new object comes in through JSON, the data table would update itself without the user refreshing the page. Here's what I have right now:

```
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Request</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Mark as Done</th>
                <th>Cannot Do</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for request in requests %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ request.room }}</td>
                <td>{{ request.request }}</td>
                <td>{{ request.time }}</td>
                <td>{{ request.done }}</td>
                <td>{{ request.cannot }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This data table (using the dataTables framework) shows all the request objects in the Django database, but only loads them once. (The Django view for the page passes in 'requests' based on a database query when the page is loaded.) I tried researching the problem and it seems like I'll need to use jQuery and/or Ajax, but I'm not sure how. I saw that dataTables has a row.add() function, but again, I'm not sure how I can implement this to update the data table with information from JSON pushed to the site.

Also, I'm envisioning this will run on a Heroku dyno. My plan is to have Heroku act as the coordinating player for a webhook, where the JSON output from another app is handed off to Heroku, which would update the database in Django and trigger the data table on the web page to dynamically update.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Any help is much appreciated, and if there's a better solution than the one I'm thinking of, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load an empty table when page load.

Use ajax in datatable for load the data
Ref [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Change the `'../ajax/data/arrays.txt'` with your `json url`

For refresh you can have a `setInterval` and call your json url via ajax and push to data table. Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593780/2956480)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the data table to display all objects in the database,
>   and when a new object comes in through JSON, the data table would
>   update itself without the user refreshing the page.

The term you are searching is the “Real-time web applications”

> This data table shows all the request objects in the Django database,
>   but only loads them once.

Yes, Because that you have implemented so far is a traditional web application where every page is loaded upon a client side request.

> I would like the data table to display all objects in the database,
>   and when a new object comes in through JSON.

To achieve this, you need to write a client side script that can listen to Server Pushes or pooling the server to get newly added data. I don’t recommended the latter method since it involves pooling.

These are your options

1. Use client side java script to pool the server. (I personally don’t
   recommend)
2. Check socket.io framework to open a two way communication between
   client side and the server side and listen to the incoming data and
   update the table using java script.
3. I strongly recommend you to use Angular to write the dynamic client
   side.